# Using Asciidoctor in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, asciidoctor

i tried to use asciidoctor gem in my rails app. I added it to my `Gemfile` and made `bundle install`.

Now i try to use asciidoctor within a Controller:

```
def show
  @article.text = Asciidoctor.render(@article.text)
end
```

But i get an error:

```
uninitialized constant ArticlesController::Asciidoctor
```

Whats the right way to user asciidoctor-gem with rails?

Comment: Silly question, since the [documentation](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor#rendering-strings) looks exactly like your example: Did you restart the server? And if so, are you using Rails 4.1/Spring?

Comment: I didn't restart the server. You solved it. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, was looking for a way to set my answer as solved. Obviously there must be at least one answer to do so.

Comment: Below your question, beside the edit link, there are another two link, "close" and "delete", which allow to cast a vote for either option. Maybe they only become visible with increasing reputation…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remember to restart your server after changing something outside the Rails auto-reloading path (i.e. `app/*` and `config/routes.rb`).

Since the [documentation](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor#rendering-strings) looks exactly like your example

```
puts Asciidoctor.render '*This* is http://asciidoc.org[AsciiDoc]!'
```

I'd guess, you simply forgot to restart the server.

Comment: I don't understand why `puts` is there. Is the context the ruby console, or is it a rails view template? If the latter, then it should be something like `<%= %>` or `=` or `==` instead of `puts`. The lack of specifying the context in documentation is probably the most confusing part for people who don't already know it inside out.

Comment: The example was copy-pasted from the AsciiDoc documentation (which, I guess, has changed since June). Of course, a `puts` in your application code will print the rendered string to `$stdout`, and will either be discarded or redirected to the log file, depending on the server configuration. I like to believe this to be basic knowledge for a web application developer...